# Смена фона Активити каждые 1,5 секунды

Tags: android

Вообщем ситуация такая. Есть Активити. Есть `LinearLayout`. Нужно реализовать смену цвета `LinearLayout` каждые 1500 мс между несколькими цветами.

API 14. Кто знает, как сделать?

Answer (score 3):

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {

    private LinearLayout ll;
    private Random rnd;
    private int[] colors;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        colors = new int[]{Color.RED, Color.BLUE, Color.GREEN};
        rnd = new Random();
        ll  = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout);

        Timer timer = new Timer();
        timer.schedule(new TimerTask(){
            @Override
            public void run() {
                changeColor();
            }
        }, 0, 1500);

    }

    public void changeColor(){
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                ll.setBackgroundColor(colors[rnd.nextInt(colors.length)]);
            }
        });

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Обленились окончательно?

Можно через:

1. Handler.postDelayed(){ меняем фон }
2. Executors Java API -> schedule() { view.post() {меняем фон }}

Таймер, как показано выше, не советую юзать. Первый вариант(Handler) -  самый приемлемый.